# C - define application version in code

Tags: c, version

I was looking throughout the internet however Google did show me results not related with what I was looking for. What I am trying to do is to define version of my program so if user will look into Control Panel to manage installed app, he will see application version like "1.0.0", "2.6.8b" etc.

Comment: The fact that you got different answers via Google should be interpreted such that you understood that your question was too broad.

Comment: there are so many possible answers, this question is clearly too broad for this site. The simplest solution is to just `#define` a version string in a common header and use that. If that doesn't suit your needs, please give more details, and ideally show some code.

Comment: You can generate the version from your version control system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VERSION_MAJOR 0
#define VERSION_MINOR 4
#define VERSION_MICRO 2
#define VERSION_SPECIAL "/beta"


#define STRINGIFY0(s) # s
#define STRINGIFY(s) STRINGIFY0(s)

#define VERSION STRINGIFY(VERSION_MAJOR)"."STRINGIFY(VERSION_MINOR)"."STRINGIFY(VERSION_MICRO)""VERSION_SPECIAL


int main(void)
{
  printf("Version: '%s'\n", VERSION);
}
```

This prints

```
Version: '0.4.2/beta'
```

---

Concluding from your edit you are referring to windows. Windows-applications handle version information as a resource.

More on `VERSIONINFO` resources here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Interesting implementation, will consider this as version definition inside app. However can you please look at updated question? As a side note, I googled something about "Resource File", I guess i have to pull `VERSION` there